# DAX Formula to analyse MoM difference

Tags: dax

I have following Table (example):

[image]

I have following matrix which calculates the difference  (Date Valid=31.10.2020):
[image]

My question / What I want to do next:
Explain the differences for each product:
==> Something like this:

[image]

Is there a DAX Formula to obtain this?

Comment: Sure. Define a measure for each explanation.

Comment: Yes but how can I define which are the new products. I have to compare current month with previous month and identify new customers. How can I define this for example? For exit I would ned to compare both months and identify which customers are no longer in current dataset.

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48992333) and the links in [this article](https://www.sqlbi.com/blog/marco/2014/06/26/calculate-new-returning-lost-and-recovered-customers-in-dax/) should help get started.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I could create now 2 measures for new and exit. However for the other 2 measures (Shift to other product / Increase or Deacrese) I need to compare if the product remained the same. Do you know how I can compare current product with previous product?